# Trouble in programming arduino with esp8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have a little problem with programming with arduino uno and esp8266.
I have connected the arduino uno with esp8266 module.

I get correct results when I run a empty program to test esp8266 with its command.

Manually entered commands with results:
[image]

When I give manually in serial monitor command AT it gives OK and correct results for all commands.

But when I try to automate with program I don,t get the output as it gives when I type manually at serial monitor could you please check my codes.

```
void setup() {      
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {    
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println("AT+RST");
    while(Serial.available())
    {
        String s=Serial.readString();
        Serial.println(s);
    }  
}
```

My output is :
[image]

My next program

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3);

void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(115200);
    esp8266.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);  
}

void loop() {
    delay(2000);
    String command="AT+RST";
    esp8266.println(command);
    if(esp8266.available())
    {
        while(esp8266.available())
        {
            char c=esp8266.read();
            Serial.write(c);
        }
    }
}
```

My result for this program is nothing on serial monitor.

I want to get the command in the program as string so that i could perform string operations like find or others when acting as a web server.

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the same command with both newlines and carriage returns. I've seen some ESP8266 modules in AT mode ignore commands otherwise.

```
// This should give you "OK" as a sanity check
Serial.print("AT\r\n");
// And then you can run this after
Serial.print("AT+RST\r\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But your solution didnt work . But I got it working. now i am getting garbage values. i have posted the question at [link]("http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18106/puts-garbage-values-at-serial-monitor-with-esp8266") . could you please look at it and help me

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3);

void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(115200);
    esp8266.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);  
}

void loop() {
    delay(2000);
String command="AT+RST\r\n";
esp8266.println(command);
c=0;
while(!esp8266.find("reset"))
{
    c++;
    if(c>100)
    {
        break;
     }
}
String Response=esp8266.readString();
Serial.write(Response);

}
```

Try this it will work definately and if in case it didnt then please swap the rx and tx pin on arduino not in code and then it will work